# Faild to install FreeSWITCH on Mac Lion with brew

Tags: macos, homebrew, freeswitch

Mac OSX 10.7.4

Xcode 4.5

Homebrew 0.9.3

```
caojinhua:~ caojinhua$ brew install freeswitch
==> Cloning git://git.freeswitch.org/freeswitch.git
Updating /Library/Caches/Homebrew/freeswitch--git
==> Checking out tag v1.2.0
==> ./bootstrap.sh -j4
==> ./configure --enable-shared --enable-static --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/freeswitch/1.2.0 --exec_prefix=/usr/local/Cellar
==> make
Creating mod_spandsp.la
brew: superenv removed: -O2
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2

Error: freeswitch did not build
Logs: /Users/caojinhua/Library/Logs/Homebrew/freeswitch/
Help: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

I have post detail logs on github gist: https://gist.github.com/3877904

Answer (score 2):

i think it's related to http://fisheye.freeswitch.org/changelog/freeswitch.git/?cs=d5d107d

updating repo's tag to version 1.3.3 solved this issue. i manually edit the Library/Formula/freeswitch.rb to reflect the change:

```
ayik@tabakan:/usr/local$ diff Library/Formula/freeswitch-orig.rb Library/Formula/freeswitch.rb 
5,6c5,6
<   url 'git://git.freeswitch.org/freeswitch.git', :tag => 'v1.2.0'
<   version '1.2.0'
---
>   url 'git://git.freeswitch.org/freeswitch.git', :tag => 'v1.3.3'
>   version '1.3.3'
```

submitted also on github homebrew issue [#16014](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/16014)